# Do I need to import code to VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, bitbucket-cloud

I am having my repository at *bitbucket*, now for CI I am creating build definition on VSTS, please note that due to team constraints, I need to continue bitbucket, so I had configured VSTS to trigger build when changes are made to master branch.

Now for placing files such as .Nuspec files, Powershell Scripts (those I need for build process), do I need to Import code from repository to VSTS? because when I go to Code > Files, it shows **Project is empty. Add some code!**

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary to import files/code into VSTS.

If you need to specify files (such as `.nuspec` or `.ps1` etc) in your build definition, you can specify the files from your **bitbucket repo** or from the **build agent machine**.

- If the files already managed in your bitbucket repo, you can select the files directly.
- If the files are not managed in your bitbucket repo, there are two options you can follow:

  **Option 1: copy the files into build agent machine**

  If you do not use Hosted agent for your CI build, you can copy the files into the build agent machine to the directory where the agent machine can access. Such as copy `test.ps1` into `C:\test\test.ps1` of the agent machine, then you can specify the powershell file with the path `C:\test\test.ps1` in your build definition.

  **Option 2: add the files into your bitbucket repo**

  You can also commit the files into your bitbucket repo. Then specify the files with relative path. Such as add the file `test.ps1` into your bitbucket repo's `mytest` directory (`rootRepo\mytest\test.ps1`), then you can specify the powershell with the path `mytest\test.ps1` in your build definition.